# Use Google Contacts API v3.0 to query Global Contacts for Subdomain [Java]

Tags: google-contacts-api

We used the Contacts API v3.0 to query global contacts(is also called directory), it is work well on the domain aaa.com but it is not work on the subdomain bbb.ccc.com.

as below code, when we set the account as admin@aaa.com and the domain as  aaa.com, it printed 319 but when we change the account as admin@bbb.ccc.com and domain bbb.ccc.com, it print 0.

```
String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "??????????";
String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "????????.p12";
String APPLICATION_NAME = "???????????";
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

String account = "admin@aaa.com";
String domain = "aaa.com";

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"))
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
        .setServiceAccountUser(account)
        .build();

if (!credential.refreshToken()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed OAuth to refresh the token");
}

ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
contactsService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
contactsService.setProtocolVersion(ContactsService.Versions.V3);
contactsService.setHeader("GData-Version", "3.0");


Query aQuery = new Query(new java.net.URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/" + domain + "/full"));
aQuery.setMaxResults(99999);
ContactFeed feed = contactsService.query(aQuery, ContactFeed.class);

System.out.println("found: " + feed.getEntries().size());
```

Are there some limits on subdomain for Google Contacts API v3.0?

Thank you.

Comment: Which command did you try?

Comment: @noogui thanks for your response and I feel sorry for the previous description is bad. I re-edit the question.